# dictionary unpacking in multiprocessing Process object

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing

I am trying to unpack a dictionary of arguments into a function I am running as a separate process, but I get an "unexpected expression" error, which is driving me crazy. I am using the "**" operator, which is giving me an error, but when I use only "*", it works but only passes the names of keys to respective arguments.

I couldn't find anyone having a similar issue on StackOverflow from other questions. Is what I am asking unreasonable? How can I fix it? Really appreciate the help.

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

class sample:

    def sample_proc_fun(self, arg1, arg2, arg3, piece_of_list):
        pass
    
    def parallel_ticker_workload(self, partial_fun_params, list_raw_file_names, n_core):
        # shuffle to distribute file sizes evenly
        list_pieces = np.array_split(list_raw_file_names, n_core)
        processes = []
        for i in range(n_core):
            p = mp.Process(target=self.sample_proc_fun, args=(**partial_fun_params, list_pieces[i]))
            p.daemon = True # kills this child process if the main program exits
            processes.append(p)
        [x.start() for x in processes]
        [x.join() for x in processes]
```

Comment: "I am trying to unpack a dictionary of arguments into a function" no, that isn't what you are doing. You are trying to use `**` as part of a tuple literal, but as the error explains, that isn't allowed (because bit doesn't make much sense)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I see now that "args" accepts only a tuple of arguments, but how can I pass a dictionary and map its content to arguments of the function that I am trying to make multiple processes of?

Comment: Can you make a running program that demonstrates the problem and include the traceback message?

Comment: See my answer, use the kwargs argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [clearly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process), `args` is supposed to be a *tuple* which will be the positional arguments, pass `kwargs` a **dictionary** of the keyword arguments... So just use

```
p = mp.Process(target=self.sample_proc_fun, args=(list_pieces[i],), kwargs=partial_fun_params)
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much! first time dealing with kwargs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll just want

```
args=partial_fun_params + (list_pieces[i],)
```

if `partial_fun_params` already is a tuple.

If both `partial_fun_params` and `list_pieces[i]` are both dicts,

```
args={**partial_fun_params, **list_pieces[i]}
```

Comment: my partial_fun_params is a dictionary though. is there a way to keep it as a dictionary and map keys to names of arguments?

Comment: See my edit. Maybe that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Not exactly, but this gave me some perspective into the args argument. thank you!